# Insert multiple rows to SQL from DataSet using LINQ

Tags: linq

I am trying to use LINQPad to query an MS Access table using DataSet, and wanted to insert the query result to a SQL table.

This is how I got the data from the MS Access table:

```
string connectionString = ("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=C:\\Temp\\temp.mdb;");
OdbcConnection myconnection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString);
OdbcDataAdapter myadapter = new OdbcDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Name", myconnection);
DataSet myCustomersDS = new DataSet();
myadapter.Fill(myCustomersDS, "Name");
```

Now In LINQPad, I wanted to insert all records from the dataset myCustomersDS to a SQL table.
I tried to query the dataset in LINQPad this way and it gives me the right result:

```
Connection.Open();
var toInsert = from b in myCustomersDS.Tables["Name"].AsEnumerable()
           select b;
toInsert.Dump();
Connection.Close();
```

I tried various versions of these commands, but always get errors related to the type of the DataSet not matching with the table type.

```
Name.InsertOnSubmit(toInsert);
SubmitChanges();
```

Thank you,
Steven

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When inserting data into a table using LINQ Table objects, you need to map out the data you want to add to objects of the table's row type.

If you had a table called `Name`, you need to create an instance of a `Name` object, fill in the values to insert, then insert it.

If inserting a single row, use `InsertOnSubmit()`.  Otherwise if you have a collection of objects to insert, use `InsertAllOnSubmit()`.

e.g.,

```
// insert a single item
Name.InsertOnSubmit(new Name
{
    Name = "Bob",
    Title = "Janitor",
});

// inserting multiple items
var toInsert =
    from row in myCustomerDS.Tables["Name"].AsEnumerable()
    select new Name
    {
        Name = row.Field<string>("Name"),
        Title = row.Field<string>("Title"),
    };
Name.InsertAllOnSubmit(toInsert);

SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: Thank you Jeff. My Name table has 67 fields. Do I have to really enumerate all the fields? I wanted to insert all fields that are in the dataset myCustomersDS, except one field called TIME_STAMP. Thanks, Steven (PS: how come I cannot insert new line in this comment? - it submits instead)

Comment: When you're mapping out the values to insert, you don't have to map all fields, just the ones you're interested in. You don't need to add the `TIME_STAMP` field if you don't want it.

Comment: Hi Jeff, I am interested in importing all the fields from the dataset, since this is a profile transfer from another institute with exactly same data structure. So there are 67 fields. I thought there might be an easier way to specify all fields. But then I guess I would have a problem excluding the TIME_STAMP field.

Comment: 67 fields is a lot. Unfortunately there isn't really an easier way to do this. Reflection is an option however, just beware of any risks involved with that. It would be safer to perform the copying manually.

Comment: Ok, I will write down all the columns. In the example you gave me you wrote InsertAllOnSubmit. I also have multiple rows. So this example would take care of multiple rows? Does it mean that the Name object will have multiple rows, or when you call InsertAllOnSubmit, it will run a loop for each row and Name has 1 row but is called multiple times in the loop? It is not that clear for me where is the loop in the code. And what is Reflection, and how can that help in this case? Thank you, Steven

Comment: Yes it will handle multiple rows. You should think of it as "inserting all (items in a collection) when you submit changes." The query (from ... select ...) part _is_ the loop.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, and for your really fast answer. Steven

Comment: Hi Jeff, sorry, 1 more question: I am still very new to LINQ, and I mostly used LINQPad to execute my scripts. In LINQPad simply using this command "Connection.Open();" I could make a connection to my database, and it used my existing configured connection. How do I connect to the database in Visual Studio and use my LINQ to SQL code? Do I need to add a LINQ to SQL class from Solution Explorer? I would prefer to write a few lines of codes instead and do everything from code. Thank you, Steven

Comment: LINQPad does quite a lot to make writing database queries _very_ beginner friendly. No boilerplate or setup needed. In Visual Studio, there is a fair amount things you need to do. You would need to generate the LINQ to SQL classes for your database. The wizards to do that should be simple to navigate. Then it's just matter of instantiating your data context (one of the classes generated) and run your queries on the context. For full instructions, this looks useful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387007.aspx

Comment: Hi Jeff. That page talks about creating an object model. I only want a simple program that inserts some records to the Name table in SQL. Can I do this with a few lines of code in LINQ to SQL? Do I really have to build the object model for this? Using ODBC seemed to be easier. Thank you, Steven.

Comment: Yes, you have to build the object model in Visual Studio. There's just no way around it. LINQ to SQL's functionality depends on a lot of that. But trust me, it's well worth it to do that.

Comment: So how is LINQPad doing it? You can just create a connection to the database and start entering LINQ to SQL queries. So I guess LINQPad is building a model behind the scenes, but is doing it from code, and when I do in Visual Studio, I have to use the designer. I thought since I only need to insert some records to 1 table I could do it from code, something similar that LINQPad is doing behind the scenes.

Comment: There's more to in than just this but LINQPad does just that. If you notice when you first start up LINQPad or refresh a connection, it might take a while until the query starts or the database schema is updated. In the background, LINQPad is generating all the classes required to make it all work. It doesn't do it in exactly the same way Visual Studio does but it's close enough. Remember, LINQPad was designed to make learning how to use LINQ simple to do. It hides a lot of what goes into setting it up so users don't have to worry about it. But it still has to be done nonetheless.

Comment: Sorry, I am still struggling

Comment: Still struggling with this.
I created a model called iMIS.dbml, then dragged the Name table there.
Now I connected to the database as:
`iMISDataContext db = new iMISDataContext();`
then:
`tblName toInsert = from row in myCustomersDS.Tables["Name"].AsEnumerable()
                select new tblName
                {
                    ID = row.Field<string>("ID"),
                    ORG_CODE = row.Field<string>("ORG_CODE"),
... and all the rest of the fields,
but I get an error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<Prog.tblName>' to 'Prog.tblName'

Comment: Post a new question for that and include all your code you're trying to use. I don't completely understand what you're doing but I have a couple of hunches on what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

There is a context driver for MS Access in LinqPad, you can download it here [Microsoft Access Data Context Driver](http://dnm-ict.nl/downloads/MSAccessDataContextDriver.ashx) 
download the .lpx-file, in LinqPad, click on Add connection, then click on 'view more drivers...' then click on 'browse' and select the .lpx-file the driver is added on the top list-box 
[image: MS Access Data Context Driver in LinqPad]